# Unable to install nginx on Ubuntu 16.04 (usr/bin/dpkg errors)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, apt

I've been trying to install dependencies for a project on a VM handled by vagrant, using vmware_fusion as the provider.

Everything appears to work fine, but as soon as I try to install nginx or sqlite3, I get output like this:

`vagrant@vagrant:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  nginx-common
Suggested packages:
  fcgiwrap nginx-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nginx-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
262 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/46.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 168 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 51773 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nginx-common_1.11.5-0+xenial3_all.deb ...
Unpacking nginx-common (1.11.5-0+xenial3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-common_1.11.5-0+xenial3_all.deb (--unpack):
 error creating directory './var/www/html': Permission denied
Processing triggers for ufw (0.35-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu13) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-common_1.11.5-0+xenial3_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

I have tried numerous suggestions, such as `sudo apt-get -f install` or `sudo apt-get upgrade` then trying again, but everything fails on the dpkg error.

I'd really appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: "error creating directory './var/www/html': Permission denied". Look at your file permissions and the user you're running as.